# Help making this image into a Tikz diagram

Tags: graphics

I am writing a research paper and I have to write it in LaTeX but I am struggling to recreate the follow image into tikz code. Thank you in advance for your help [image]

Comment: Welcome. // Even, if you struggle, you can still post your best attempt ... no need to be shy ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that on this site we don't exactly love *do-it-for-me* questions. However, I'm on lunch break...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\x in {30,150,270} {%
   \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,text=blue,font=\Large] at (\x:1) {$\boldsymbol+$};
   \draw[blue,very thin](\x:1)--(0,0);
}
\foreach\x in {90,210,330} {%
   \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,text=red,font=\Large] at (\x:1) {$\boldsymbol-$};
   \draw[red,very thin](\x:1)--(0,0);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]